# google charts graph view on page load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-visualization

I realized graphic on my web page with using google charts library. it adds to the page by AJAX, into `<div>`.

I want to show graph when page load, for this i write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload =function()
    {
      callgraph();
    }         
</script>
```

callgraph- my function to draw the graph.

```
function callgraph() {
    var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/graph/data',
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
      //  alert('xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
}
```

It works, but sometimes  graph does not load when I refresh the page. 
When I change data at form, and call my function, it always work normally.

Then I call my function two times with delay.Using this method graph appears all times.

```
 window.onload =function(){ 
    setTimeout(callgraph, 250);callgraph();
 }
```

But I think it's not good way, to call function two times.

drawChart function

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
   
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line'],callback: drawChart});

 function drawChart() {
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'Day'); 
     data.addColumn('number', 'Heads');
     data.addRows([

     <?php

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
     {  
         echo '[ \''.$row['Date'].'\' , ';     
         echo $row['HeadCount'].'  ],';      
     }
     ?>
     ]);

     var options = {
         title: '',
         height: 640,
         vAxis: {
             viewWindow: {
                 min: 0,
             }
         },
     };

     var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
</script>
```

Can you advise what to do?

Comment: please share the code that draws the chart, you can use `google.charts.load` instead of `window.onload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't know the code that comes from your ajax request, but it sounds like you're trying to draw the chart before google api gets fully loaded. Please keep in mind that you should always draw the chart using the callback provided by the api, like this:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

That's probably the reason the chart loads after some timeout.

Comment: I use this: `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line'],callback: drawChart});` . I think it's the same.

Comment: In my opinion, you could have that code already in your page. When the chart api gets loaded (drawChart) you make the ajax call, and it should return only the data needed for the chart (json). With a json array, you can then draw the chart.

Comment: I use `<?php echo 'data'; ?>` to send data into js, instead of JSON. May be problem in this?

Comment: If you call the function just once, do you get any error messages from the developer tools console?

Comment: Yes, when graph don't display, appear the  error: `Error: Container is not defined` from www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_default_module.js .Does this mean that the library did not boot completely?

Comment: By this error message, it looks like 'chart_div' is not already in the page when the library tries to draw the chart. Try to put 'chart_div' directly in your page and not in the code that comes from ajax.